# How to collect statistics of `View` in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark version: 3.0.0

Here are some codes:

```scala
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option(...)
    .load(tablePath)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")

// suppose we have create views "t2" and "t3".
val res = spark.sql("select * from t1, t2, t3 where t1.a = t2.a and t2.b = t3.b")
```

I'm using SparkSQL to create View by reading CSV files. And I want to tune the sql performance by collecting the table statistics which may help the optimizer to generate a better execution plan.

I find the document about the syntax `Analyze TABLE`. But my `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` are views instead of tables, so I cannot use `Analyze Table t1 ...`.

Here is my question:
How to collect statistics of `VIEW` in SparkSQL to help CBO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful-

```scala
  val df = spark.range(10)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("myView")
    spark.sql("explain cost select * from myView").show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |plan                                                                                                                                                                    |
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |== Optimized Logical Plan ==
      * Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=Some(2)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=80.0 B, hints=none)
      *
      * == Physical Plan ==
      * *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=2)|
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      */

println(spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes) // 80
```